# Fixed header overlays main content

Tags: html

I am trying to *make my header fixed* for that in the header div I am adding `position:fixed` and `width:100%`

Now after doing this, my main content overlays on header. So as a fix, I found on search that in main-content div I can add margin-top equivalent to height of header.

When I am doing this, I am getting my header shifted. As in suppose if I add margin-left as 100px. My header top shifts by 100px and main content still overlays on header content.

Any fix?

Comment: Give some example code.

Comment: Do you have `top: 0` for your header?

Comment: Yes...it has to be right!!

Comment: @user1508372 Please create a small demo for us; you can do so at http://jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the margin in the content from the top equal to the header height and z-index to your header if fixed.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="content">Content</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.header{
    background:#F00;
    height:100px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:10
}
.content{
    background:#0C0;
    margin-top:100px;
    height:2000px;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/epKv8/

I would never suggest to add `position: absolute;` in content div.

Comment: Hi, when I do this in jsfiddle..it is working fine. Even on a sample application. But I add this code in actual website, I can see my main-content contents passing behind the header div as I scroll down.

Comment: they set css as .content{position:relative; z-index:-1} position:relative doesnt effects the code in bad way.

Answer (score 0):

Give this css to your main-content div:

```
#main-content /* replace # with . if its a class*/
{
position:absolute;
top:/*height of header*/;
left:0px;
}
```

Its working correctly for me.See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xPutK/1/

Use `z-index` property of css to adjust depth of elements.

Comment: Ok i will create a fiddle

Comment: now i added .headerClass{position: fixed;
height: 150px;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 10;}                                                            .contentClass{margin-top:150px;}     Now it does not overlays header, but when I move my scroll-bar, the main-content content is passing through header div

Comment: Hi, I am able to do this on a sample. But when I use this code on my actual website code...it is shifting the main-content margin. But as I scroll up, I can see the text passing by behind my header div. I cant even post the code as I am using really complicated template of a company.

Comment: Just post the part of the code of header and main-content because my solution should solve it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44513/discussion-between-zword-and-user1508372)